# Why PostgreSQL not using index properly?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, database-performance, sqlperformance

**Schema:**

```
create table records(
  id         varchar,
  updated_at bigint
);
create index index1 on records (updated_at, id);
```

**Query**. It iterates over recently updated records. Fetches 10 records, remembers the last one and then fetches next 10 and so on.

```
select * from objects
where updated_at > '1' or (updated_at = '1' and id > 'some-id')
order by updated_at, id
limit 10;
```

It uses index, but it doesn't uses it wisely and also applies filter and processes tons of records, see `Rows Removed by Filter: 31575` in query explanation below.

The strange thing is that if you remove `or` and leave either left or right condition - it works well for both. But it seems like if can't figure out how to apply index correctly if both conditions are used simultaneously with `or`.

```
Limit  (cost=0.42..19.03 rows=20 width=1336) (actual time=542.475..542.501 rows=20 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using index1 on records  (cost=0.42..426791.29 rows=458760 width=1336) (actual time=542.473..542.494 rows=20 loops=1)
         Filter: ((updated_at > '1'::bigint) OR ((updated_at = '1'::bigint) AND ((id)::text > 'some-id'::text)))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 31575
 Planning time: 0.180 ms
 Execution time: 542.532 ms
(6 rows)
```

Postgres version is `9.6`

Comment: `... where updated_at > '1'  ... ` You should not quote integer literals.

Comment: @wildplasser I tried it without quotes, same thing.

Comment: `width=1336` That is a *very* wide table,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try this as two separate queries, combining their results like this:

```
select *
from
  (
    select   *
    from     objects
    where    updated_at > 1
    order by updated_at, id
    limit    10
    union all
    select   *
    from     objects
    where    updated_at = 1
      and    id > 'some-id'
    order by updated_at, id
    limit    10
  ) t
order by updated_at, id
limit    10
```

My guess is that the two queries would each optimise pretty well and running both would be more efficient than the current one.

I would also make those columns NOT NULL if possible.

Comment: Yea, I also thought about that. But I thought PostgreSQL is smart enough and maybe there's some mistake in my code...

Answer (score 2):

There is an optimization of the calls to the index made by PostgreSQL.

> For example, given an index on (a, b, c) and a query condition WHERE a
>   = 5 AND b >= 42 AND c < 77, the index would have to be scanned from the first entry with a = 5 and b = 42 up through the last entry with a
>   = 5. Index entries with c >= 77 would be skipped, but they'd still have to be scanned through. This index could in principle be used for
>   queries that have constraints on b and/or c with no constraint on a —
>   but the entire index would have to be scanned, so in most cases the
>   planner would prefer a sequential table scan over using the index.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/indexes-multicolumn.html